# addChildEventListener not working for java app

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm trying to implement Firebase admin SDK in Java app. I want to add `childeventlistener` to child and when child added i want to take value of child and store into system clipboard . Here is my `main.java` file so far:

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount =
            new FileInputStream("path/to/.jason");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("xxxxxxxxxx")
            .build();
    Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    StringSelection data;

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = firebaseDatabase
                .getReference().child("ClipSync");

        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                cliptext string = dataSnapshot.getValue(cliptext.class);
                Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                StringSelection data;
                data = new StringSelection(string.getText());
                c.setContents(data, data);
                System.out.println("Child added");


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    while (true){}
}
}
```

My `cliptext` class:

```
public class cliptext {
String text;

public cliptext(String text) {
    this.text = text;

}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

}

Problem I am facing:

1. When child is added to database at that time code shoud trigger addChildeventlistner but that not happening.
2. i am able write data to database and also able to retrive it so there is no problem in firebase-admin setup.

Note : Not getting any compiletime or runtime error  &  i am using intellij idea in linux .

Comment: I know very little about threading in the Admin SDK, but I'm wondering why you have `while (true){}` at the end of `main()` and whether this is affecting the ability of the listener to run.  Also add a `System.out.println()` to `onCancelled()` to see if it is being called.

Comment: @BobSnyder He might be using that `while (true) {}` hack to keep his app from *terminating* while he waits for the network response. Anyway, weird stuff... ;)

Comment: @PauloMattos: Probably true.  So in the Admin SDK, do callbacks run on the Main thread?  I would guess yes.

Comment: @BobSnyder I would say yes, because that's what Firebase does on other platforms. If so, as you initially said, this will cause a deadlock-ish situation...

Comment: @Bob Synder ya that while loop is for preventing my app from exit as i wanted to run it as background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a constructor that takes *no arguments* to your `cliptext` class. The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) makes this clear:

> - The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments
> - The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value when an instance is deserialized

Might not fix *all* your issues, but you will need to do this as well eventually ;)

Comment: Ya thx buddy this is right answer . I just have to add constructor with no argument in my cliptext class. Thxx it work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain, but expect that the Admin SDK is similar to the client SDKs, in which listener callbacks run on the "main" thread.

At the end of method `main()` you have a busy-wait loop, `while (true){}`.  You are likely doing this to prevent `main()` from completing, which would cause your app to terminate.  Doing that totally occupies the main thread and never gives the listener an opportunity to run.  You will need to find another way to pause `main()` to give the callback a chance to run.